# python for android package for making an APK

Tags: android, python

i have ran the command :

./build.py --dir ~/utils/helloworld     --package org.test     --name "Hello2" --version 1.0 debug installd

and i saw an APK in bin folder but still the output has been stopped at the following last sentence so i dont get it that what should i do with this process and how much time it will take to complete or it is completed..please tell me what should i do after this sentence because this is not the end of the process..

-post-build:

debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 7 seconds
Buildfile: /home/kajal/python-for-android/dist/default/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

install:
     [echo] Installing /home/kajal/python-for-android/dist/default/bin/Hello2-1.0-debug.apk onto default emulator or device...

```
 [exec] error: device not found
 [exec] error: device not found
 [exec] error: device not found
 [exec] - waiting for device -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have successfully built the APK file.  It is automatically trying to install it on either an android device that is connected to the computer via USB, or on an android emulator set up on the computer itself.  However, it cannot find either of the two so it would wait forever until you connect an android device.
You have a few choices:

1. Plug an Android device into the computer:
   Make sure before you do that it is in debug mode (go to Settings->Applications->Development->USB debugging), and that it allows installation of third-party applications (go to Settings->Applications->Unknown sources).  Your android device might have a slightly different settings location, but it shouldn't be difficult to find.  Finally, if it does not work automatically when you plug in the phone, then you probably need to download and install the correct drivers for your phone.
2. Set up an emulator:
   To do this you will need to have installed the Android SDK.  If you are in Eclipse look for a button at the top that has an Android on it.  Otherwise search for a program called "AVD Manager".  I think you can also access it from the Android SDK program.
3. Install the APK on the phone manually.
   This may actually be (initially) the most convenient method.  Simply close the program if you want, and then copy the generated APK file to your phone.  Then use a file browser on your phone to open the file and install it (you will need to have enabled installation of third-party applications as before).

Persevere!